# list_display rows in a table conditionally django

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, admin, customization

I have two tables

```
Employee
-----
username
organisation_id
email

Organisation
------------
organisation_id
company_name

User_A->organisation_1
User_B->organisation_1
User_C->organisation_2
User_D->organisation_2
```

when user_A login he should only see User_A and User_B
This code should be like below,
logic is first we need to find the current user organization and conditionally display the results in admin page 
 Django admin code

```
admin.site.register(Employee, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Organization)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
def filter_view(request):
current_user = request.user
organization_id =employees.objects.get(id=current_user.id).organization_id
List_display = ('username', 'email','Organizations.objects.filter(id=organization_id)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [**`get_queryset(request)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method:

*I am assuming you have a onetoone relation between employee and user*

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Then override the `ModelAdmin` class like this:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
     def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(organisation_id=request.user.employee.organisation_id)
```

Comment: Working outside of request context. Error is occuring

Comment: thank you very much . and i'm pasting my code here for helping others

''class RestrictedFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
    def get_queryset(self, request):

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super().get_queryset(request)
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(organization_id=request.user.employee.organization_id)
        admin.site.register(Employee,RestrictedFormAdmin)''

Answer (score 1):

You can write `list_display` is...

```
list_display = ('username', 'email', 'filtered_organisation')
```

And write a method for filtered_organisation as below...

```
def filtered_organisation(self, obj):
    return Organizations.objects.filter(id=organization_id)
```

For more reference [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question for helping others, I modified my code like this for multiple user types, this code will help you for that situation so that only users related to the department can see other user but superuser can control everyone. thankyou for @ruddra and @MK Patel for your valuable effort.

```
>     class RestrictedFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>         class Meta:
>             model = Employee
>         def get_queryset(self, request):
>             if request.user.is_superuser:
>                 return super().get_queryset(request)
>             return super().get_queryset(request).filter(organization_id=request.user.employee.organization_id)
> 
>     admin.site.register(Employee,RestrictedFormAdmin)
```